# OKTA - Get username from profile claims in C# Load_Page method

Tags: .net, okta, okta-api

We’re developing a custom sign in page. Actually, we’re using the [Okta Sign In Widget](https://developer.okta.com/code/javascript/okta_sign-in_widget) on an aspx page. The reason we’re doing this is because we must integrate with another .NET API library.

So far, everything out of the box works great. User goes to page, is shown the sign in screen, signs in and is given .aspx page.

To go further, we need to write some code in the Page_Load() event of the .aspx page that checks to see if the user is authenticated and if so, extract the username from the claims collection. Once that is done, we will do some work with the other API and then redirect to another application, passing the username and the token received from Okta.

I’m not finding how I can acquire this information in C# in the Page_Load() event.

Any assistance would be very much appreciated.

best,
x

Answer (score 0):

You need OKTA SDK - https://github.com/okta/okta-sdk-dotnet.

To authenticate a user/request, pass access_token obtained from sign-in widget as Authorization header. API should check this Authorization header. For example, here is my .NETCore Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(...) {
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
      .AddJwtBearer(options =>
      {
        options.Authority = <your_authorization_url>;
        options.Audience = <your_api_audience>;
      });
   ...
}

public void Configure(...) {
    ...
    app.UseAuthentication()
    ...
}
```

Then, you can use [OKTA Client GetUser](https://github.com/okta/okta-sdk-dotnet#get-a-user) to retrieve user profile inside a service.

```
public class MyService {
  ...
  public void GetUser(string userId) {
    var client = new OktaClient(new OktaClientConfiguration
    {
       OktaDomain = <your_okta_domain>,
       Token = <okta_api_key>
    });
    var user = await client.Users.GetUserAsync(userId);
  }
}
```

You can use OKTA Client without Authentication, but I recommend you should do it. Hope you find it helpful.